# Isolating $x$ in logarithmic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd just like to check that I'm using the right technique. I have the following function and I am trying to isolate $x$:

$$ \ln(x) + \ln(x-1) = 1$$
I take $e^x$ of both sides:
$$ x + x-1 = e$$
$$2x – 1 = e$$
$$2x = e+1$$
$$x = \frac{e+1}{2}$$

The reason I ask is because wolfram is giving me a completely different answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ and not $e^a+e^b$ so you should get the quadratic $$x^2-x=e$$

Answer (score 4):

Careful.  You're on the right track with taking $e^x$ on both sides.  However, doing this to the *entire* left side, we get:

$$e^{\ln(x) + \ln(x-1)} = e^{\ln(x)}e^{\ln(x-1)}$$

This is due to properties of exponentiation.  Now, we can simplify down to:

$$x(x-1)$$

From here, the problem becomes finding the roots of a quadratic polynomial.  Applying the quadratic formula, you'll arrive at two possible solutions for $x$.  However, the negative solution won't be valid since the natural logs in the original equation are only defined for positive values of $x$.